# Why can't I click on links on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, css, click, touch-event

I am developing a site ([saulesinterjerai.lt](http://www.saulesinterjerai.lt)) Everything works now, except on mobile device the links are not clickable, instead it goes through to other layers..

How do I disable this behavior from the code? (not on browser)

The code that I wrote is here, however some parts of code I copied from the web (everything in "dep" folder if you know how to use dev tools). I also do suspect it could be problem with `pjax` or the proprietary "zoomable" module, but I can't find why..:

```
var pjax = new Pjax({ selectors: ["head title", "body"] })
var Site;

var attach_menu_control = function() {
  var $sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
  var $sidebar_content = $sidebar.querySelector('.content')
  var $menu_opener = $sidebar.querySelector('.menu-closed')

  var hide_menu = function() {
    $sidebar_content.style.display = 'none'
    $menu_opener.style.display = 'block'
    $sidebar.style.width = '40px'
  }

  var show_menu = function() {
    $sidebar_content.style.display = 'block'
    $menu_opener.style.display = 'none'
    $sidebar.style.width = '270px'
  }

  var click_handler = function(e){
    // e.preventDefault()
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if ($sidebar_content.style.display == 'none') {
      show_menu()
    } else if (width <= 724) {
      hide_menu()
    }
  }

  if ( !is_touch_device() ) $sidebar.addEventListener('click', click_handler)
  $sidebar.addEventListener('touchend', click_handler)
  var event = new Event('click');
  $sidebar.dispatchEvent(event)
}
attach_menu_control()

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', reloadCarbon)
document.addEventListener('pjax:complete', reloadCarbon)
document.addEventListener('pjax:send', resetCarbon)

// Animations

document.addEventListener('pjax:send', function(){
  var $main = document.querySelector('main')
  $main.style.opacity = 0
})

document.addEventListener('pjax:complete', function(){
  var $main = document.querySelector('main')
  $main.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  $main.style.opacity = 0
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('main').style.visibility = 'visible'
    document.querySelector('main').style.opacity = 1
    attach_menu_control()
  }, 10)
})

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function is_touch_device() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers 
      || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
}
```

CSS:

```
    .menu-closed {
        font-size: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      top: 50%;
      padding-left: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .sidebar {
        transition: width 0.2s;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        z-index: 10000;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .sidebar .content {
        width: 270px;
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 724px) {
        .sidebar {
            background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.87);
        }

        .sidebar h1 {
            font-size: 36px;
        }

        .sidebar header h2 {
            font-size: 28px;
        }

        .language {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .sidebar nav > ul > li {
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        .sidebar nav > ul.siteLinks a, 
        .sidebar nav > ul > li > a {
            font-size: 36px;
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        main {
            padding-left: 40px;
        }

        /* Force sideback to be in closed mode when new page is opened */
        .sidebar {
            width: 40px;
        }

        .sidebar .content {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    /* Emulate fixed positionin */

    html {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .fixed {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: not sure where is the problem, on my Android everything works fine

Comment: I do have the same problem on my Nexus 6P/Chrome, that's weird. I'll have a look on my dev phone.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin does it work now that I updated the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to this function, which gets called:

```
 var click_handler = function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if ($sidebar_content.style.display == 'none') {
      show_menu()
    } else if (width <= 724) {
      hide_menu()
    }
  }
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the browser to perform the default action, here: to switch pages and follow the URL in the link.

I guess you have to be careful on which item you attach this handler.
This kind of handler does not feel very natural on a link.

This was highlighted by the Chrome console's warnings:

```
Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
click_handler @ app.js:34
```

**EDIT**

I see a lot of handlers attached to your elements, and I don't understand each one's role (i don't know the pjax lib for instance), I think one is responsible of the loss of the expected behavior. If I were you, maybe I'd try to make it simpler and rewrite the menu system and its integration in the webpage.

If you can't (or don't want to) refactor the page, maybe don't try to fix it but try a workaround.

What I would do is to add a transparent grey backdrop when the menu is open, to show the user the rest of the screen is disabled (or full transparent and when the user clicks/taps on it, it closes the menu to go back to the main content). 
When the menu is open, you set on the main content the following css:

```
pointer-events: none
```

This will prevent the pictures/content under the menu to receive events, and only the menu should get click/tap events. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi sjahan, I added this for this `preventDefault` to prevent clicksthrough to underlying layers, because instead of opening the menu it would open the images and zoom them in. Now that I removed it - it opens the images behind the menu (which should be another question I guess, so if this doesn't get solved I will post it in different angle). HOWEVER, even with the version before - you could click the links in normal browser, the only problem being mobile (so WHY?)

Comment: Look at the last lines of the CSS - could this be due to this way of trying to position the menu as fixed (the normal way doesn't work)

Comment: With a quick look, i can't see a problem with the css, though, it's probably that when you tap on the link, the event is bubbling up into many event handlers and end up canceled. I'll try to have look at it deeper! Now, the links are working but the menu is acting weird, can you set it back as it was?

Comment: thanks .. the only difference is the commented `e.preventDefault()`, u can uncomment it in dev tools. I modified the question according to current code. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I accepted your answer as it's probably the only one I will get. However I still can't click through the links on mobile.. any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you change something else? I took a look right now, but now the menu is closed on the mobile version and i cannot open it. Strange thing is that there is no event listener attached on elements, while on the desktop version, there are a lot of them (on the menu links for instance).

Comment: Check now, the menu should open, but same exact problem - it doesn't register a click, instead the click goes through to the layer under (to zoom in the image if you are on a project).

Comment: I added a potentiel solution in the main answer! Hope this will help you. Just like that, i don't see what's going wrong but as I stated, there are a lot of handlers implied and that's hard to get which one is wrong and is it normal or not...

Comment: thanks, I found the solution, it was the Pjax library that didn't cover touch events. Once I manually fire click event on each touch event - it works. You could call it a workaround probably..

Comment: I posted the solution on separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723508/how-to-enable-touch-events-on-pjax-library