# How to enable touch events on pjax library?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, pjax, dom-events

I am developing a site where I use [Pjax](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax) library (a port of jquery pjax). However the touch events don't go through. I am using Pjax like so:

```
var pjax = new Pjax({ selectors: ["head title", "body"] })
```

and also have some animations:

```
document.addEventListener('pjax:send', function(){
  var $main = document.querySelector('main')
  $main.style.opacity = 0
})

document.addEventListener('pjax:complete', function(){
  var $main = document.querySelector('main')
  $main.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  $main.style.opacity = 0
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('main').style.visibility = 'visible'
    document.querySelector('main').style.opacity = 1
    attach_menu_control()
  }, 10)
})
```

I need it to work on mobile. The site is [www.saulesinterjerai.lt](http://www.saulesinterjerai.lt) (can be buggy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it works by redirecting touch event to click event like this:

```
if (is_touch_device()) {
  var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')
  var event = new Event('click');

  for (var index = 0 ; index < all_links.length ; ++index) {
    all_links[index].addEventListener("touchend", function() {
      all_links[index].dispatchEvent(event)
    });
  }
}

function is_touch_device() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers 
      || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
}
```